# Existence of unique solution on $(-\delta,\delta)$ for $f(x)=1+x+\displaystyle\int^x_0\sin(tf(t))dt$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The following was a question previously given in a test at my university:

> Show that there exists some $\delta>0$ for which there is a unique
>   continuous function $f:(-\delta,\delta)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
>   $$f(x)=1+x+\int^x_0\sin(tf(t))dt$$ and give a value of $\delta$ for
>   which this is true.

($\mathbb{R}$ has the Euclidean metric) I'm really not sure what to do with this question. If it were on a closed interval I think I could use the Banach contraction theorem to show that some mapping $Q$ with $Qf=f$ if and only if $f$ satisfies the above equation is a contraction, then finish. Or, I think Picard's theorem might've worked too, but the fact that it's an open interval has got me pretty confused.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Cauchy Lipschitz theorem.

Let $Lf(x) = 1+x+\int^x_0\sin(tf(t))dt$. Let us prove that $L$ is Lipschitz on the space of continuous functions defined on $(-\delta, \delta)$ for $\delta$ small enough.

\begin{align}|x|< \delta \implies
|Lf(x) - Lg(x)| &=\left| \int^x_0 |\sin\left(t(f(t)-g(t))\right)|dt\right|
\\&\le
\left| \int^x_0 |t(f(t)-g(t))|dt\right|
\\&\le \sup_{|x|< \delta} |f-g| \int_0^{|x|} tdt 
\\&= \sup_{|x|< \delta} |f-g|
\frac{\delta^2}2
\end{align}

Now if $\delta$ is small enough, $\delta^2 < 2$
you can apply the Picard theorem on the complete space $C(-\delta, \delta)$ with the metric of uniform convergence.

Comment: Why $|x|\le\delta$ instead of $x<\delta$?

Comment: @user188500 thia was a typo :)

Comment: Okay, I see how this works now, thanks.